# CMake using the wrong linker flags (dynamic vs static)

Tags: c++, boost, linker, cmake

I'm compiling my program statically, like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(statictest)

set(LINK_SEARCH_START_STATIC ON)
set(LINK_SEARCH_END_STATIC ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME ON)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX})
SET(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES OFF)
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem system program_options regex thread chrono)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(LIBS ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(test
  "src/test/main.cpp"
  )
target_link_libraries(test ${LIBS})
```

The linker line should contain static linkages for BOOST as I've found the **static** version of the libraries.

Here is the linker line cmake generates:

```
/usr/bin/c++   -g    -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ CMakeFiles/test.dir/src/test/main.cpp.o -o test -rdynamic -Wl,-Bdynamic /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.a /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.a /usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options.a /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex.a /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.a /usr/local/lib/libboost_chrono.a
```

Notice the `-Wl,-bdynamic` before all of the **static** BOOST libraries ending in `.a`. How do I force CMAKE to link these with the static flag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LINK_SEARCH_END_STATIC](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/LINK_SEARCH_END_STATIC.html) is the target property, you have to apply it on the target itself:

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(test PROPERTIES LINK_SEARCH_END_STATIC 1)
```